# Probability of "manmade global warming is a problem with solutions that are cost-effective"

Tags: probability, independence

I came across [this](http://www.crisismagazine.com/2017/hurricanes-climate-change-pope-francis-poor) post from a climate change skeptic, which made the following point (emphasis mine):

> However, if Pope Francis is right that history will judge us, we need to decide what, if any, action is called for by asking **four questions: Is the earth warming? Is that an overall bad thing? Is human activity the primary cause? And would forced standards be cost-effective?**
>
> Regrettably, none of those questions can be answered with absolute confidence because our knowledge is limited by data, finite in number and dependent on processes that, in some cases, are not fully known and, in others, not even identified. As already discussed, answering the first question and most basic with any degree of confidence is unlikely.
>
> Yet **even if each of those questions could be answered in the affirmative with 80 percent probability, their cumulative probability would be 41 percent**, indicating the proposition that “manmade global warming is a problem with solutions that are cost-effective” is, at best, problematic.

I get the calculation ($0.8^4=0.4096 \approx 41\%$). However, I feel there is something wrong here. The above calculation seems to assume the answers are entirely independent. But they are clearly not. For example, if the Earth is not warming, then this is clearly not a bad thing, nor there is a cause to nothing, so humans cannot be such cause to nothing. Therefore, the first question kind of makes the other three redundant.

Similarly, if human activity is the cause of global warming, a cost-effective solution is more likely to exist that if global warming is not due to human actions. Thus, there last question is not independent of the other either.

How would one go to properly address this problem then? Do we need complete information of the joint distribution of the answers to the four questions?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but in practice be aware that the more specific we are, the lower the probability. So for example, saying that the next person we meet will have two legs and each leg will have five toes is less probable than saying the person will have two legs, full stop. So while the first claim seems somehow better (more complete), it is the second one that is more probable.

Comment: Or with the theory of evolution: the more specific we make it, the more complete, intuitive and acceptable it might seem; but the less probable it is. So I should trust more firmly a claim that a species A developed into whatever (general) and then into species C than the more coherent claim that A developed into B which developed into C (where B is something in between A and C by its appearance).

Comment: As you say, the arithmetic here is just $0.8^4 \approx 0.41$. That's not a cumulative probability, but a joint probability based on an assumption of independence. Whether it's worth even reading this stuff is the bigger issue!

Comment: @NickCox haha good point. I was curious about what is the argument of climate change skeptics.

Comment: For what it's worth I'd parse those as conditional probabilities, so $\Pr(A,B,C,D) = \Pr(D|C,B,A) \Pr(C|B,A) \Pr(B|A) \Pr(A)$

Comment: @Scortchi That's a good point here, but are you implying that the original thinkers were that subtle? (I declare a bias to trust consensus climate science here, and critically,  including a bias of participating in a small way to environmental science literature.)

Comment: @NickCox: IMO they may well have been thinking along the lines of:-"If the Earth's warming, is that a bad thing? And then if it is a bad thing [..]". But a charitable interpretation of the calculation does nothing to diminish the pointlessness of plucking the probabilities out of thin air to start with. Ill-defined probabilities at that.

Comment: @Scortchi We agree, naturally.

Answer (score 6):

I usually parse such arguments as involving conditional probabilities

$\Pr(A,B,C,D) = \Pr(D|C,B,A) \Pr(C|B,A) \Pr(B|A) \Pr(A)$

which is formally correct without any assumptions of independence. (Rather like the [Drake equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation).)

Formal correctness doesn't make up for vagueness in the definitions of the events<sup>†</sup>, or for our being expected to nod along with numbers pulled out of thin air:—"80%'s quite a good chance, he's being fair there, isn't he?".<sup>‡</sup> A cynical reader might suppose that an intial description of the outcome as a conjunction of affirmative answers to *three* questions (each with a generous-sounding 80% probability) didn't yield a low enough joint probability to make the point.

† Which isn't the only reason these "yes/no" questions would surely better be posed as "how much" questions.

‡ Moreover, as @gung points out, we're entitled to some explanation of the concept of *probability* being used here, presumably one quantifying degree of belief rather than long-run frequency.

Comment: This is a charitable interpretation of the statement, but I'm still not sure that it is coherent. Eg, the probability that the earth is warming is either $0$, or $1$, no other values are possible.

Comment: @gung: I was also assuming epistemic rather than frequentist probabilities - something like a Bayesian perspective. Of course it behoves someone quantifying probability to be clear what they mean by it - I'll edit this point in.